# Playstore Error: Remove conflicts from the manifest before uploading

Tags: flutter, firebase, flutter-dependencies, google-play-console

I am trying to upload first release on Google Play Console. I've tried to upload bundle file and got the following error:

```
Remove conflicts from the manifest before uploading. 
The following content provider authorities are in use by other developers: com.propel.firebaseinitprovider, com.propel.flutter.image_provider.
```

I've checked the code of **AndroidManifest.xml** of [FirebaseInitProvider](https://github.com/firebase/flutterfire/blob/master/packages/firebase_core/firebase_core/android/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml) from Firebase core Package.

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="io.flutter.plugins.firebase.core">

    <application>
        <service android:name="com.google.firebase.components.ComponentDiscoveryService">
            <meta-data
                android:name="com.google.firebase.components:io.flutter.plugins.firebase.core.FlutterFirebaseCoreRegistrar"
                android:value="com.google.firebase.components.ComponentRegistrar" />
        </service>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

I've also checked another **AndroidManifest.xml** of image_picker.

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="io.flutter.plugins.imagepickerexample">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

    <application android:label="Image Picker Example" android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher">
        <activity android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivity"
                  android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar"
                  android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|locale|layoutDirection"
                  android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
                  android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <meta-data android:name="flutterEmbedding" android:value="2"/>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Both Manifest file contains different providers, I don't know why I am getting this error.

I've already refer official [documentation](https://developer.android.com/build/manage-manifests#node_markers) for different node markers.

Can anyone help on this?

Note: I've not any  in AndroidManifest file of my own project.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The package name `com.propel` is already available in Google Play Store
[Google Play Link](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.propel). Try to change the package name and upload.

Comment: What if my package name is not present in Google Play Store? [Google Play Link](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.news.updates)  i am facing same provider kind of Issue for Firebase , admob ads & Facebook ads Providers only.

Please provide some solution.
Thanks in Advance !!!

Comment: You still need to change your package name as it may be conflicting with generic package name.

Answer (score 1):

In simple terms your package name is conflicting with other packages available on GooglePlay Store.

`com.propel` before the provider used.

Answer (score 0):

Replace activity tag.
From:

```
 <activity android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivity"
              android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar"
              android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|locale|layoutDirection"
              android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
              android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
```

TO

```
<activity android:name=".MainActivity"
              android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar"
           android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|locale|layoutDirection"
              android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
              android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
```

Comment: What will be FROM & TO?

Comment: Please check now